# Comparing IP v6 addresses

Tags: ip, ip-address

has anybody some good ideas to compare two ipv6 addresses. It look like the shortage rules are making it complicated.

for instance the full address
1234:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:ff00:0011

1. leading zero can be removed   =>  1234:0db8::::ff00:ff00:11
2. one group of empty fields can be removed 1234:0db8::ff00:ff00:00111
3. the last 32 bit can be an old fashioned ipv4 address 1234:0db8::::ff00:172.0.0.15

Comment: *Normalize* them into either their most compact form or their full form before comparison...

Comment: Step 1 is wrong. It should be `1234:0db8:0:0:0:ff00:ff00:11`. Although technically correct, a single `0` is not leading any longer, because there is nothing which it could lead. Otherwise, `1234:0000:0000:4321:0000:0000:0000:0001` could be converted to `1234:::4321::::1`, which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the standard library function `socket.inet_pton` to convert the addresses into a byte string for comparison:

```
>>> socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6,'1234:0db8::ff00:ff00:0011')
'\x124\r\xb8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\xff\x00\x00\x11'
>>> socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6,'1234:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:ff00:0011')
'\x124\r\xb8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\xff\x00\x00\x11'
```

This will reduce the risk of you creating your own IPv6 bug.

---

Example above is in python, but the `inet_pton` function is available on different platforms and languages:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805844(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html

Answer (score 0):

You could just split it by colons and then compare each value.
If you encounter an empty field -> insert '0000' for it.
If you encounter a field with less than 4 digits -> fill it up with zeroes

Additionally you could give each of the fields a weight to emphasize the values of the fields.